# PHP Merger Array Object

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

i have some problem how merger this array. could help me ?

**First array :**

```
Array
    (
        [22] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 22
                [post_author] => 1

            )

        [23] => WP_Post Object
            (
                [ID] => 23
                [post_author] => 1

            )

    )
```

**Second array :**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [img_thumb] => small_duck.jpg
                [img_full] => duck.jpg
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [img_thumb] => small_fish.jpg
                [img_full] => fish.jpg
            )

    )
```

**Should OutPut :**

```
   Array
        (
            [22] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 22
                    [post_author] => 1
                    [img_thumb] => small_duck.jpg
                    [img_full] => duck.jpg

                )

            [23] => WP_Post Object
                (
                    [ID] => 23
                    [post_author] => 1
                    [img_thumb] => small_fish.jpg
                    [img_full] => fish.jpg

                )

        )
```

The array key follow first array,

Comment: Consider using array_merge function of php http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
$first = array(
    22 => array(
        'ID' => 22,
        'post_author' => 1
    ),
    23 => array(
        'ID' => 23,
        'post_author' => 1
    )
);
$second  = array(
    array(
        'img_thumb' => 'small_duck.jpg',
        'img_full' => 'duck.jpg'
    ),
    array(
        'img_thumb' => 'small_fish.jpg',
        'img_full' => 'fish.jpg'
    )
);

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($first);
var_dump($second);

$i=0;
$should = array();
foreach ($first as $key => $arr) {
    if(isset($second[$i]))
        $arr = array_merge($arr,$second[$i]);

    $should[$key] = $arr;
    $i++;
}

var_dump($should);
```

Comment: SOLVED, Thank for @Barry