# Fill Value At Key Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have some array like that

```
[11] => Array
        (
            [hotlink_thumb] => http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHzF0iX9-f-P6BBDriiPKNMLYFAsikzPIbAWL0eZLH14ujpZkv
            [hotlink_source] => http://homeoidal.pro/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/outdoor-furniture-interesting-diy-outdoor-furniture-design-featuring-natural-brown-wicker-rattan-sectional-sofa-with-brown-padded-seat-cushion-and-cool-grey-pillow-plus-brown-rectangle-striped-plank.jpg
            [alt] => 
            [caption] => 
            [description] => 
            [href] => http://localhost/wordpress/homemade-patio-furniture/furniture-tv-media/
            [src] => 
            [title] => Furniture Tv Media 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [hotlink_thumb] => http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtYn0sWBKe8XIWgvmg7IBcNCB63oSwPEVGxKc6b5w8z3DPSRV_IA
            [hotlink_source] => http://www.widmeyer-construction.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Redwood-Benches-005.jpg
            [alt] => 
            [caption] => 
            [description] => 
            [href] => http://localhost/wordpress/homemade-patio-furniture/furniture-tv-deals/
            [src] => 
            [title] => Furniture Tv Deals 
        )
```

and then i have another array

```
[0] => Array (

[alt] => the alt one
[caption] => the caption one

)

[1] => Array (

[alt] => the alt two
[caption] => the caption two

)
```

but i want

```
[11] => Array
        (
            [hotlink_thumb] => http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHzF0iX9-f-P6BBDriiPKNMLYFAsikzPIbAWL0eZLH14ujpZkv
            [hotlink_source] => http://homeoidal.pro/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/outdoor-furniture-interesting-diy-outdoor-furniture-design-featuring-natural-brown-wicker-rattan-sectional-sofa-with-brown-padded-seat-cushion-and-cool-grey-pillow-plus-brown-rectangle-striped-plank.jpg
            [alt] =>  the alt two
            [caption] => the caption one
            [description] => 
            [href] => http://localhost/wordpress/homemade-patio-furniture/furniture-tv-media/
            [src] => 
            [title] => Furniture Tv Media 
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [hotlink_thumb] => http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTtYn0sWBKe8XIWgvmg7IBcNCB63oSwPEVGxKc6b5w8z3DPSRV_IA
            [hotlink_source] => http://www.widmeyer-construction.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/Redwood-Benches-005.jpg
            [alt] => the alt two
            [caption] => the caption two
            [description] => 
            [href] => http://localhost/wordpress/homemade-patio-furniture/furniture-tv-deals/
            [src] => 
            [title] => Furniture Tv Deals 
        )
```

Comment: I think the most interesting question would be how did you create these 2 arrays. Maybe the best answer would be to look at that and see if you cannot create your desired array in one go rather than attempt to FIX it after they are built

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same problem as your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224453/php-merger-array-object

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $array1 contain your first array data you posted above.

$array2 contain your second array data you posted above

```
<?php 
$cnt = 0;
foreach($array1 as $key => $arr1) {
  $array1[$key]['alt'] = $array2[$cnt]['alt'];
  $array1[$key]['caption'] = $array2[$cnt]['caption'];
  $cnt++;
} 
?>
```

Comment: This will work, but only if you have BOTH arrays in the same order and BOTH arrays of the same size